# Unexpected output from redirection

Tags: bash, vim, io-redirection

I'm encountering a strange problem when redirecting STDOUT and STDERR.  The following works as expected:

```
$ gvim --version > /tmp/version.out
$ ls -l /tmp/version.out
-rw-r--r--. 1 blah blah 3419 Jun 27 17:28 /tmp/version.out
```

There are **3419** characters in the output file and when I look at the file, it contains what I expect.

However, it does not work as expected when I do the following:

```
$ gvim --version > /tmp/version.out 2> /tmp/version.err
$ ls -latr /tmp/version.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 blah blah 0 Jun 27 17:29 /tmp/version.out
-rw-r--r--. 1 blah blah 0 Jun 27 17:29 /tmp/version.err
```

Notice that both the .out and the .err files are zero length this time.  I tried this with an **ls** command and it works as expected:

```
$ ls . /ZZZ > /tmp/ls.out 2> /tmp/ls.err
$ ls -l /tmp/ls.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 blah blah 50 Jun 27 17:45 /tmp/ls.err
-rw-r--r--. 1 blah blah 33 Jun 27 17:45 /tmp/ls.out
```

Here, the STDERR gets redirected properly:

```
$ cat /tmp/ls.err
ls: cannot access /ZZZ: No such file or directory
```

I did an strace on **gvim --version** and confirmed that it's trying to write the version info to STDOUT (fd 1).  It shouldn't matter either way though since I'm trying to capture both STDOUT and STDERR.

What's going on here?

Comment: I'm seeing a whopping 8188 `ioctl(2,...)`s that return with `ENOTTY`. It looks like gvim does some TTY stuff on STDERR, even when just running `--version`. Reading the source would be the next step to determine why.

However, this is when run from within `strace`, which might mess with STDERR in the first place.

Comment: @KevinMGranger, if you want a less invasive means of doing comparable tracing (across a whole system with very little performance overhead), consider [sysdig](https://www.sysdig.org/).

Comment: @KevinMGranger - I noticed that too.  But, I'm still not sure how that leads to no STDOUT when trying to also redirect STDERR.

Comment: @KevinMGranger  - actually, I see a lot of ioctl(2,...) but they all return zero in my case.

Comment: @KevinMGranger - _actually_, when I run `strace` and redirect _that_ output to a file, then I see lots of `ioctl(2,...)` with `ENOTTY`.  Otherwise, just letting the `strace` output default to my terminal, the `ioctl(2,...)` lines have a return code of zero.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations, you just found a bug in `gvim`!
Correct procedure is to [file a new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues).

You should first try another variations of the bug, so that developers have the debugging easier.

For example, redirecting only STDERR also causes the error, because there was no output written. Also there was returned success (0), which is obviously an bug.

```
$ gvim --version 2> /tmp/version.err
$ echo $?
0
```

By only looking into the code one may search for the bug somewhere in [version printing](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/da5116da4586fc714434411d2cccb066caa3723e/src/version.c#L2280-L2281), or anywhere in generic --version argument processing, [not being done by gtk](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/b463e8d999ec812d656876f313efbeaeed663b45/src/gui_gtk_x11.c#L368-L370).

### To answer your question

What is going on?

**It's a program error**, made by developers of `gvim` and I would not recommend you to put effort into finding its root cause unless you are experienced with coding `vim` or if you want to learn, how `vim` works. In that case, your best shot is to [fork the repo](https://github.com/vim/vim) and after fixing it, submitting a pull request, so that everyone can benefit from your work.

Comment: The specific condition that triggers the bug seems to be *when stderr is not a terminal*. When I tried redirecting stderr to another tty, the `--version` message was still printed to stdout. Apparently Vim uses `isatty(2)` to help figure out if it should use a terminal at all. From [`gui.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/gui.c): "For GTK and X11 we check if stderr is not a tty, which means we were (probably) started from the desktop." (But the rest of that comment, and instances of `isatty(2)` throughout multiple files, make it not immediately obvious what ought to be changed.)

Answer (score 1):

The specific condition that triggers the bug seems to be **when standard error is not a terminal**. When I tried redirecting standard error to another terminal device, the `--version` message was still printed to standard output.

```
ek@Io:~$ gvim --version 2>/dev/null
ek@Io:~$ tty
/dev/pts/1
ek@Io:~$ who
ek       tty7         2017-07-05 02:48 (:0)
ek       pts/1        2017-07-10 09:10 (192.168.10.3)
ek       pts/3        2017-07-10 09:23 (192.168.10.3)
ek@Io:~$ gvim --version 2>/dev/pts/3
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
....
```

Apparently Vim calls `isatty(2)` to help figure out if it should use a terminal at all. From a comment in [`gui.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/gui.c):

> Return TRUE if still starting up and there is no place to enter text.
>   **For GTK and X11 we check if stderr is not a tty, which means we were (probably) started from the desktop.** Also check stdin, "vim >& file"
>   does allow typing on stdin.

But the rest of that comment (i.e., the part I didn't highlight), and instances of `isatty(2)` throughout multiple files, make it not immediately obvious what ought to be changed.

Running `grep -RF 'isatty(2)'` on the source tree revealed that this is used in [`gui.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/gui.c), [`message.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/message.c), and [`main.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/main.c). (That *doesn't* mean the bug is in all those files, of course.) You might also look at [all the instances of `isatty` in the source code](https://github.com/vim/vim/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=isatty&type=).

In any case, as [jirislav says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44933905/1038860), this ought to be reported as a bug--even if a full explanation of the problem is not yet apparent. I am able to reproduce this with the current upstream sources ([commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commits/master) [163095f](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/163095f088a7c29710a16c75bb56229dd3b4116a)).